# Merging two tables in SQL with ProgrammingError of Ambiguous column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, pyodbc, ambiguous

I am trying to merge two tables. I am a bit new at this, but I believe the tables are dbo.Detail and Com.All_Calls_List

dbo.Detail has three columns I want to get: CallID, and ResponsibleParty
Com.All_Calls_List has four columns: CallID, CompanyName, Receiveddate, CustomerType

I want to merge the tables by CallID and add ResponsibleParty as a column to the table.

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=MYDSNCONNECTION")
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

cursor.execute("select CallID, CompanyName, recvd_dttm, CustType, ResponsibleParty from dbo.Detail, Com.All_Calls_List where Com.All_Calls_List.CallID = dbo.Detail.CallID")
```

This is giving a Programming Error of `[SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Ambiguous column name 'CallID'.` I looked up this error and I understand that it is because CallID is a duplicate column in both tables. I have read up on how other people have solved it, but their tables and goals were different enough that I could not figure out how to apply it here. Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select Com.All_Calls_List.CallID, CompanyName, recvd_dttm, CustType, ResponsibleParty
from dbo.Detail join Com.All_Calls_List 
on Com.All_Calls_List.CallID = dbo.Detail.CallID
```

It is suggested you use the table-name if a column exists in both tables. Also, as you are joining the tables on `callID` selecting from either table gives you the same result.

Comment: Interesting. That makes sense, and your solution worked. Thank you.